# Compile with stix font?

Tags: fonts, stix

I feel like this shouldn't be too hard to accomplish but I haven't been able to figure it out from some quick googling. On ubuntu, I have the font-stix package installed, and the fonts are actually on my computer (mathjax is rendering with it, for example), but I don't know/understand how to compile a regular LaTeX document (via, eg, `pdflatex`) with the stix fonts.

edit: I came across that other link when I was googling but nothing there was able to help me get stix working.

Comment: The package `xits` is included in TeX live and has a good documentation. The STIX Opentype fonts are also included, and they are used the same way like all Opentype fonts are used in Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX, _but not with PDF(La)TeX_.

Answer (score 6):

I downloaded the stix latex beta package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/stixfonts/,
The added the following to preamble

```
\usepackage{stix}
```

(and deleted my old font setup, of course)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)